# NixOS Build Error: "dbus/dbus.h" not found

Tags: nixos, nix

I'm trying to build the "nvidiaBeta" driver, but it fails to build nvidia-settings with the error

> gtk+-2.x/ctkgridlicense.c:38:23: fatal error: dbus/dbus.h: No such file or directory

I have tried installing all kinds of dbus packages but the closest thing I get in my nix store is a "dbus-c++/dbus.h" from the dbus_cplusplus derivation.
While searching I've read that apparently what I need is supposed to be contained in "dbus-libs" but it doesn't seem to be available in channel 17.03.

I cannot seem to figure out which derivation is supposed to pull in this library. Can I somehow work around the issue and get it to use the one I have from the dbus_cplusplus derivation?

Comment: What commands are you executing to build the nvidiaBeta driver?

Comment: I'm just defining services.xserver.videoDrivers = [ "nvidiaBeta" ];
in my configuration.nix and then building with nixos-rebuild switch. As for the dbus libraries I've been trying to install as well I am also just adding them to my configuration.nix file before building

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already been mentioned Nix won't care about system or user installed packages when building a package, and the package in question needs to declare all of its dependencies explicitly.

Regarding this specific issue - the `dbus/dbus.h` file can be found in the `dev` output of the `dbus` derivation. Nix also provides facilities for overriding package definitions and we can use those to feed `dbus.dev` into build inputs of nvidia settings. Adding the following to `configuration.nix`:

```
nixpkgs.config.packageOverrides = pkgs:
{
  linuxPackages = pkgs.linuxPackages.extend(self: super: {
    nvidia_x11_beta = super.nvidia_x11_beta // {
      settings = super.nvidia_x11_beta.settings.overrideAttrs(old: {
        buildInputs = old.buildInputs ++ [ pkgs.dbus.dev ];
      });
    };
  });
};
```

allows the build to succeed on my 17.03 system.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks. I'm still learning and know a little about how to override packages to get dependencies. But I was completely hitting a wall without even knowing where the dbus.h file it needed was supposed to come from

Answer (score 0):

Unlike other distros, on NixOS even if you happen to install the right libraries it won't make a difference because packages must declare their dependencies for a build to succeed.

For example, if you try to build package *A* and it depends on package *B*, installing package *B* won't provide the dependency; package *A* simply won't see it.

As for Nvidia, I do not see *nvidiaBeta* as an option. You can use "nv" which is the open-source driver, or "nvidia" which is the proprietary driver. See https://nixos.org/nixos/manual/#idm140737316337280

Comment: I heard it mentioned in the IRC a while back and I also see it in here: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/hardware/video/nvidia.nix
But also it wouldn't even begin compiling if it wasn't defined somewhere. When I build it I actually see it pull in nvidia beta drivers and it fails during compiling nvidia-settings.

Comment: I see. Well, then your best course of action is to create a bug report on the nix packages collection Git repo on GitHub.